# Why is passing by value actually having the effect of being passed by reference [C Language]?

Tags: c, parameter-passing

`

```
// Global Variable
float game_camera_projection_matrix[4][4];

void start(void)
{   
    // Renderer
    {
        //Camera
        calypso_framework_math_matrix_matrix4f_ortho(game_camera_projection_matrix,-8,8,-4.5f,4.5f,-1,1);
        
        // Create Default Shader Program Red
        game_default_shader_program_red = calypso_framework_renderer_2d_opengl_create_default_shader_program();
        calypso_framework_renderer_2d_opengl_set_current_render_shader_program(game_default_shader_program_red);
        calypso_framework_renderer_2d_opengl_set_current_shader_program_parameter_vec4f("color_in",1,0,0,1);
    }
}
```

`

```
void calypso_framework_math_matrix_matrix4f_ortho(float matrix4f[4][4], float left, float right, float bottom, float top, float near, float far)
{
    matrix4f[0][0] = 2.f/(right-left);
    matrix4f[0][1] = matrix4f[0][2] = matrix4f[0][3] = 0.f;
    matrix4f[1][1] = 2.f/(top-bottom);
    matrix4f[1][0] = matrix4f[1][2] = matrix4f[1][3] = 0.f;
    matrix4f[2][2] = -2.f/(far-near);
    matrix4f[2][0] = matrix4f[2][1] = matrix4f[2][3] = 0.f;
    matrix4f[3][0] = -(right+left)/(right-left);
    matrix4f[3][1] = -(top+bottom)/(top-bottom);
    matrix4f[3][2] = -(far+near)/(far-near);
    matrix4f[3][3] = 1.f;   
}
```

Full source.
https://github.com/wayfarerGameDev/calypso_framework/tree/main/src

My projection matrix should still not be set as I am not passing the address. I am honestly very confused. I am coming from C++. I could not return array in C so I worked on my matrix code and printed out matrix to test if ortho code was working and when I ran it was just working as if I was using the new modified value.

Comment: C does not support directly passing arrays as parameters. Syntax that looks like that actually passes a pointer to the first element due to something called array to pointer decay. The common way of passing an array is by passing a pointer to the first element and the length & yes this means that the original array is accessed by the fcn. A work around is passing a struct that has an array member.

Comment: Exactly! The name of the array decays to the pointer pointing to the first element of the array.